# How to work around a filled status bar in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**I am missing a [status bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) overflow management** ([issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6651)). It seems to be not an issue to many people, because the issue was closed with not enough votes and I cannot find other issues that address this problem.

**My status bar is filled and some important ongoing task information or even buttons for actions or infos are not shown** (depending on the screen or window size one uses).
First I thought the automatic activation of extensions and their entries in the status bar might solve the issue, but it doesn't. It is just a question of probability when all extensions are activated and use more space in the status bar than available.
I also could remove extensions to some degree, but I am down to a minimum already.

**A manual solution is to hide entries in the status bar via right click on it.**
Doing so helps immediately but introduces another problem. *(Additionally, for me,  it is not easy to accept that I have to do this in the first place - it seems wrong to do it manually and can be done automatically, but somehow no one needs or wants it)*
**Hiding entries in the status bar manually affects all other folders or workspaces I open in vscode afterwards.**
If some entry is hidden in one workspace - where I need space for other entries - it is also hidden in another workspace or folder that I open and where I need to see the hidden entry. Therefor I have to manually show it again and - because of missing space - hide something else.
I might want some entries shown in the status bar in one folder and hide them in another folder or workspace.

**How do you all work around this problem?**
Is this problem not that important or even not existing for you? Why?

Comment: Note: some extensions provide settings to use more compact version of their statusbar indicators. Ex `"cmake.statusbar.visibility": "compact"`

Comment: I believe this is an issue for everyone and that most people _(me included)_ are just forced to use a broken status bar that's unwieldy/almost-unusable. _(as for the GH issue being closed, it feels like that's due to it relying on a bigger issue of "voting" on GH issues not being a proper voting solution that surfaces items to vote on to the user-base/teaches the users how to vote on them. Most users don't know how to "vote" on an issue and there's no user feedback on if your vote actually counts/notifies the devs of it's importance.)_

Comment: @skplunkerin How many VSC users monthly browse the new issues for feature requests. Very few. Not me. That is the reason of the low vote count. We should add a feature request for UI that regularly shows the list of new feature requests in VSC and we can easily vote from this UI. How do we get it a high vote count?